# saving macro adds another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a modified piece of code that saves a macro into a specified folder. It works great, however it opens a blank workbook upon completion. I do not want that to happen. I am aware it has to do something with the following

> workbooks.add

But since the variable has to be set, is there a way around that? I am fairly new at this and I just don't want to screw it up haha. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Anyways, here is the piece of code

```
    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    wb.Activate
    If IsFileOpen("\\showdog\service\Service_job_PO\" & UserInput) Then
    Workbooks(UserInput).Close SaveChanges:=False
    wb.SaveAs "\\showdog\service\Service_job_PO\" & UserInput    
    Else
    wb.SaveAs "\\showdog\service\Service_job_PO\" & UserInput 
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If
```

Comment: Need to see more code - at least as far as the `End If` associated with the `If IsFileOpen...` statement

Comment: Oops. Didn't realize I forgot that. I added the rest of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is creating a new workbook and setting a variable to that workbook:

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
```

Then it activates the current workbook, bringing it to the foreground:

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

Then, for some reason immediately brings the new blank workbook front and center:

```
wb.Activate
```

Then it checks to see if some file is open. If it is, it closes it (not sure what this is since we don't know what `UserInput` is. Anyway, it closes that file, then saves the new blank workbook over the top of it. Just the blank work book.

Is that your desired behavior? If you want to close this newly saved blank workbook, then just do...

```
wb.close
```

...at the end of all of that. But, honestly, the whole thing seems a little strange.